# How can I make a smaller video when it has limited unique frames?

Tags: codec, file-formats, h.264

I'm currently editing a podcast that is mainly audio with only three unique images shown on screen. However, using h264 encoding gives me a massive file, how can I leverage the limited number of unique frames to reduce the file size?

Comment: Welcome! How exactly are you creating and encoding the video right now? What tools are you using? What operating system?

Comment: @MichaelLiebman Hi Michael, I realise it's been a while, life got in the way. At the moment I'm using premiere pro, on windows 10. I believe I'm using the h.264 or h.265 codec.